# The next and previous controls of the default video screen with AVPlayerViewController - AVQueuePlayer, is not working

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avqueueplayer

I have a list of songs to play in AVPlayerViewController, so I use AVQueuePlayer to play it. All the songs are kept in the bundle.

Now, the default video screen I get the things functioning are:

- Play/Pause
- Auto switching to next video after completion of previous
- Fast forward the current video  ('>>|')
- Fast backward the current video ('|<<')

The things not working which is needed **must** are:

- Previous functionality with the provided '|<<' control, to go to previous video.
- Next functionality with the provided '>>|' control, to go to next video.

This I have done so far -

```
var arrAVPlayerItems = [AVPlayerItem]()
     for i in 1...4 {
         let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample-\(i)", withExtension: "mp4")
         arrAVPlayerItems.append(AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL!))
     }
     let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: arrAVPlayerItems)
     playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
     playerViewController.player = player
     playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true
```

The situation here is that I will have to use only the default screen controls, and not make custom ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this demo https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hmxrLGwM6zTm4wYS14aWcxOEU/view

Comment: player.allowsExternalPlayback = true add this in your code

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya, Thanks .But this does not make the >>| button to go to next video, though fast-forwarding the current video was happening (without adding 'allowsExternalPlayback = true' also)

Comment: @JeckyModi , Thanks. But the demo uses custom controls. I need the exact functionality as in Apple's default Music app. The same '>>|' button should fast-forward the current video, plus move to the next video, differing in the way to tap it.

Comment: @AdarshRoyChoudhary I will try by myself, if you have demo can you send me?

Comment: @JeckyModi, here is the demo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0l971TMJKqWVnQtTUsyQmQwUGs